# Angular, call function in directive from controller (broadcast?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not too sure I am taking the best or correct approach to this, but basically what I am tyring to do is call a function in a directive. The reason being is I'm trying to clear a scope out that is controlled in the directive. For reference I am using this https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete directive, and the desired effect is when I add the selected item, it would clear out of the input.

So what I am trying to do is after I add the selectedObject to my list where I am storing (the add function) I am calling a broadcast to the directive like so

```
$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete:clearInput');
```

So for reference, here is the entire add function that is called

```
$scope.addLesson = function(){
    var skillCheck = true;
    for(i=0;i<$scope.lessonsHere.length;i++){
        if($scope.lessonsHere[i].id === $scope.testObj.originalObject.id ){
            errorOffScreen("You cannot add the same Lesson more than once");
            skillCheck = false;
        }
    }

    if(skillCheck){
        $scope.lessonsHere.push($scope.testObj.originalObject);
        $scope.testObj = {};
        $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete:clearInput');
    }
}
```

So in the directive itself I just have

```
$scope.clearInput = function(responseData, str) {
            console.log("hit!");
         };
```

It seems it does not work, I am not sure if this is the right approach, but I found another directive that calls itself from the controller with a broadcast so I figured it must be a good starting point.
Would appreciate any help here, as I am a bit in the dark with this topic. Thanks for reading!

Comment: can you please create a little demo on plunker?

Comment: How much such directives are u going to have on page? Because if u share object between controller and directive - u can just change it in controller and that's it.